# Error when loading package "tmap" in library

Tags: r, tmap

I want to use the function tm_shape, therefore I attempted to load tmap but here is the error when I load it in the library

```
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tmap’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
     there is no package called ‘terra’
```

Comment: Did you install it?

Comment: Did you install terra?

Comment: No because this is what I have when I want to ":Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) library(terra)
Error in install.packages : Unrecognized response “library(terra)”"

Comment: I suggest you first try to solve not being able to install terra and then try again with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and that was because you did not install 'terra' first. I installed 'terra' and everything worked.